# Pass text from MKMarkerAnnotation to different view controller

Tags: swift, firebase, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am trying to pass text from my markers on MKMapView to a different view controller when the markers are tapped. I tried using one method after reading online but since the view controller I'm passing the text to doesn't have a navigation controller, I don't think it will work. Note that I am also using Firebase to retrieve data that will be displayed on markers and the reason the view controller looks odd is becuase I am using [ISHPullUp](https://github.com/iosphere/ISHPullUp#ishpulluphandleview)

Visual Representation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv4qp.jpg

Code from TopViewController (MKMapView and MKMarker data)

```
var mainTitle = ""
```

.

```
Database.database().reference().child("posts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for snap in snapshot.children {
            let postSnap = snap as! DataSnapshot
            if let dict = postSnap.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                let title = dict["title"] as! String
                let locationName = dict["location"] as! String
                let discipline = dict["category"] as! String
                let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: dict["lat"] as! Double, longitude: dict["long"] as! Double)
                let artwork = Artwork(title: title, locationName: locationName, discipline: discipline, coordinate: coordinate)
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(artwork)
            }
        }
    })
```

.

```
extension TopViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard let annotation = annotation as? Artwork else { return nil }
        let identifier = "marker"
        var view: MKMarkerAnnotationView
        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
            as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeuedView
        } else {
            view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            mainTitle = annotation.title!
        }
        return view
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "bottom") as! BottomViewController // Didn't work
        myVC.stringPassed = mainTitle
        navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
        print(mainTitle)
    }
}
```

Code from BottomViewController (View Controller I'm trying to send the text to)

```
var stringPassed = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    toplabel.text = stringPassed
}
```

Code from ViewController

```
class ViewController: ISHPullUpViewController {
    private func commonInit() {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let contentVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "content") as! TopViewController
        let bottomVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "bottom") as! BottomViewController
        contentViewController = contentVC
        bottomViewController = bottomVC
        bottomVC.pullUpController = self
        contentDelegate = contentVC
        sizingDelegate = bottomVC
        stateDelegate = bottomVC
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `didSelect` delegate method of `MKMapViewDelegate`

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        if view.annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return
        }
        let ann = view.annotation as! Artwork
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let bottomVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "bottom") as! BottomViewController
        bottomViewController = bottomVC
        bottomVC.pullUpController = self
        sizingDelegate = bottomVC
        vc.stringPassed = ann.title
}
```

//

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if segue.identifier == "bottom" {
      let nextScene =  segue.destination  as! BottomViewController 
      nextScene.stringPassed = sender as! String
    }
}
```

//

Also to be able to use `push` instead of segue embed  `TopViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`

Comment: Would this work as TopViewController and BottomViewController aren't connected by a segue?

Comment: You can present it , performSegue but VCs should be connected in IB or push it with navigationcontroller if TopVc embeded inside a navigation see edit

Comment: These are how the two ViewControllers are connected to each other https://pastebin.com/9Epkwiaq

Comment: then use present